# kafka-spark streaming in docker

Tags: docker

I am new and inexperienced in the world of containers and docker systems. I want to write a producer/consumer in Kafka and set up some streaming and ETL using pyspark. Now I am well aware of the process and the technical background required.

All I want to know is if I just had to create a small demo of the above and share the files with my students in a docker so that all they would have to do is install it on their end and see how it works, is that even a possibility?

Comment: Did u search on google , I think you didn't, if you will ask specific question will help to answer, many tutorial and link available on google to guide you .https://www.confluent.io/blog/getting-started-with-the-kafka-streams-api-using-confluent-docker-image/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a simple [docker compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) with the required deployment and share the docker compose artifacts with the students.

Furthermore, you can have a look at [WSO2 Stream Processor](https://docs.wso2.com/display/SP430/Stream+Processor+Documentation) which provides an interactive UI to write the streaming and ETL related logic if you are not bound to Spark.